# SQL server count and Sum Query?

Tags: sql, count, sum, common-table-expression

I have a Question table with the fields (QuestionID,QuestionMarks), and with the data fields look like -

```
 QuestionID   QuestionMarks
   1              1
   2              4
   5              1
   9              1
   12             2
```

which means at the moment Question table has 5 Question of Total 9 marks, Now my problem is that i want to know that a combination of 4 Questions with 8 marks is possible and fetch out that combination ( in general a combination of "x" questions of "y" marks is possible) ?

I was thinking to use CTE, but was afraid that it will take lot of time to execute the query if i have tens of thousand question.

please suggest some idea how to get the data. I am using SQL Server version 2008

Comment: Either I'm counting wrong, or your sample and commentary don't match up (I see 8 marks in total in your sample). Also, any way you slice it, I think it's a combinatorial explosion.

Comment: yea sorry that was my mistake the last question with QuestionID =12 is of marks 2, now edited

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - so there is no safe way to do it in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a *start*. It's going to have poor performance:

```
declare @Qs table (QuestionID int not null, QuestionMarks int not null)
insert into @Qs (QuestionID,QuestionMarks) values
(1,1), (2,4), (5,1), (9,1), (12,2)

declare @TargetMarks int = 8
declare @TargetCount int = 4

;with Build as (
    select QuestionID as MinID,QuestionID as MaxID,QuestionMarks as Total,1 as Cnt
        ,'/' + CONVERT(varchar(max),QuestionID) + '/' as QPath
    from @Qs
    union all
    select MinID,q.QuestionID,Total+q.QuestionMarks,Cnt+1,QPath + CONVERT(varchar(max),q.QuestionID) + '/'
    from
        Build b
            inner join
        @Qs q
            on
                b.MaxID < q.QuestionID and
                b.Total + q.QuestionMarks <= @TargetMarks and
                b.Cnt < @TargetCount
)
select * from Build where Cnt = @TargetCount and Total = @TargetMarks
```

Result set:

```
MinID       MaxID      Total       Cnt         QPath
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2           12          8           4           /2/5/9/12/
1           12          8           4           /1/2/9/12/
1           12          8           4           /1/2/5/12/
```

The tricky part is that the QPath value isn't exactly the greatest way of storing ID values.

Comment: thanks buddy,let me understand it and will get back to you.Just wanna know that,this solution will be okay performance wise like if i have thousands of rows in the table ?

Comment: @user1509581 - the only way to know would be to try it out on your hardware/OS, with your data, and to set specific performance criteria - what's acceptable for one person may not be for another - do you need the result in < 1 second, some small number of seconds, a few minutes, or just so long as it's before the heat death of the universe. Performance is very subjective.

Comment: got your point, a few seconds will be okay for me, anyway is running perfectly okay on machine until now. Thx

Comment: what if i want to get the id's of any one combination not how many combinations are possible ?

Comment: @user1509581 - I've added a new column - it gets all the IDs, but not necessarily in an easy to further transform/consume manner

Comment: (Damien_The_Unbeliever) - Thanks buddy that works for me and very much helpful , thumbs up!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right in that tens of thousands of questions can slow down execution, so I'd start by limiting the potential rows being queried. You already know for certain that even with millions of rows, you never need more than four with identical QuestionMarks and you can reduce this further, e.g. (sorry for not knowing whether SQL Server accepts this syntax)

```
WITH LimitPotentialRows AS 
(SELECT m1.QuestionID, m1.QuestionMarks, 
 (SELECT SUM(m2.QuestionMarks)
  FROM MyTable m2
  WHERE m1.QuestionMarks = m2.QuestionMarks
    AND m1.PrimaryKeyID <= m2.PrimaryKeyID) CurrentMarks,
 (SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM MyTable m3
  WHERE m1.QuestionMarks = m3.QuestionMarks
    AND m1.PrimaryKeyID <= m3.PrimaryKeyID) TotalQuestions
 FROM MyTable m1
 WHERE m1.QuestionMarks <= :DesiredTotalQuestionMarks - :TotalNoOfQuestions + 1
 HAVING CurrentMarks <= :DesiredTotalQuestionMarks
    AND TotalQuestions <= :TotalNoOfQuestions)
```

Desiring 4 questions with a total of 8 marks, the result of this CTE will leave you with only

```
QuestionMarks NumberOfQuestions
       1              4
       2              4
       3              2
       4              1
       5              1
```

Having limited the number of rows from tens of thousands to maximum 12, you're unlikely to have performance problems in your further calculations.